# Simple index definition in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, indexing, doctrine-orm, annotations

Is there a *simple* way to define a non-unique index over a column?

When I define unique index, this is perfectly sufficient:

```
/** @ORM\Entity */
class Foo {
    /** @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true) */
    private $foo;
}
```

However, for non-unique index, I need this bunch of boilerplate:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(indexes={@Index(name="foo_idx", columns={"foo"})})
 */
class Foo
{
    /** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
    private $foo;
}
```

I'd prefer something like `@ORM\Index` annotation on the single property, or `index=true` etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to disappoint you...

```
@ORM\Table(indexes={@Index(name="foo_idx", columns={"foo"})})
```

is as simple as the annotation can get.

If `$foo` would be a relating entity it would be indexed automatically, but for indexing fields you need to add the index as you did.

You can find all `@Column` attributes [here in the Doctrine 2 documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#column). Sadly enough `index` is not among them.

Maybe you can make a feature request [here on GitHub](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2).